# Why pdfjs-dist is not working for Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, promise, pdf.js

I have a react build using yarn. It produces three files:

- `main.hash1.chunk.js`
- `2.hash2.chunk.js`
- `pdf.worker.hash3.chunk.js`

Under IE, the last file errors with `Error: 'Promise' is undefined`

`core-js` is already setup but it doesn't appear to be included in `pdf.worker.hash3.chunk.js`.

`index.js`:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Switch
} from "react-router-dom";
import { Theme } from "./theme";
import { Chart } from "./pages/Chart";
import "typeface-libre-franklin";
import "typeface-roboto";
import "./polyfills.js";
import pdfjs from "pdfjs-dist";
import "core-js";

ReactDOM.render(
  <Theme>
     <bunch of other tags />
  </Theme>,
  document.querySelector("#root")
);
```

Comment: Besides installing the library, are you importing it as mentioned in the [docs](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js)? Also, if you can please paste the complete output you get from IE.

Comment: I've got 'import "core-js";' in my index.js file.  Note: without that line it still builds with the same hash in my pdf.worker file.

The output from ie is a window alert that says "Error: 'Promise' is undefined."

Comment: Have you check the console log? Maybe you can share a screenshot of it.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's at a client site, embedded ie in an application, with no way to bring up the console.

The only time I got rid of that error was when I modified node_modules/pdfjs-dist/pdf.js...   which is bad practice.  And then it complained about isNaN not being defined.

Comment: Which version of IE are you trying to support? Can you paste how the `index.js` looks like? Just in case, [here's](https://reactjs.org/docs/javascript-environment-requirements.html) React take on enabling features.

Comment: `
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Switch
} from "react-router-dom";
import { Theme } from "./theme";
import { Chart } from "./pages/Chart";
import "typeface-libre-franklin";
import "typeface-roboto";
import "./polyfills.js";
import pdfjs from "pdfjs-dist";

ReactDOM.render(
  <Theme><plusextrastuff...?
  </Theme>,
  document.querySelector("#root")
);
`

Comment: Why won't that paste as code?

Comment: Maybe editing the question will do :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, that in my build environment, the issue was resolved with having the correct version of pdfjs-dist installed.

I had 2.6.347 and had to downgrade to 2.2.228.  Once that was done, it no longer made a pdf.worker.hash.worker.js file and instead made a longer-hash.worker.js file that works with what I needed it to.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution to this issue. I suggest you try to mark your own answer to this question after 48 hrs when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding.